# Centralizing data AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, branch

I want to centralizer about 1TB of data in AWS for 3 on premise locations (5 users each location). We are going growing but still small. Each location has a 30/5mpbs connection. Each has its own Linux Server. I believe I know what to do, but I have a couple of questions.

1.) Seeing that data will be in the cloud, I want to optimize the traffic between on premise and AWS. Is there a Linux version of Branch Cache? Or something to store locally between the on premise and cloud? Storage gateway is a ONLY IF we cannot find any other solution.

2.) Am I better with s3,ebs,efs? (There is package that will mount s3 bucket).

3.) If I choose ebs/efs (with a instance), are transfer rates slower or faster vs s3? Does s3 use optimization?

Comment: What kind of data, how is it accessed and used, and do the locations share the data? I know that's a pretty broad or vague set of questions, but there are many, many things that can go wrong over the WAN that work fine on the LAN.  If you're talking about something like an MS-Access (Jet) database, you don't even want to try it.  Other cases are not so clear-cut, but more detail is needed in order to understand the application.

Comment: Sure . Files like documents ,images ,and any other application saved files. From what I've read attaching Ebs to a instance then connecting on prem via samba would work, but no caching or optimization. Would I be better with something like cachefs or maybe toffee/wan proxy for optimizing?

Comment: The real issue is money because if I use a wan optimization technology such as riverbed I am not really saving much money by centralizing on aws.

Comment: Yeah, for files being opened and saved by humans, you'll almost certainly need something to provide some magic local optimization.  Of course, storing 1TB of data locally, even on redundant disks, is not an expensive proposition these days.  Perhaps what you really need from the cloud is coordinated backup/sync/mirror rather than to "centralize" to a common primary backing store. 1TB is going to run you $30 in S3, $100 on EBS, or $300 on EFS, but resist the teptation to try emulating a filesystem with S3.  It isn't one, and s3fs makes a valiant effort to bridge the gap, but it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Amazon Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/). Though I never used it myself so can't give more details beyond what's in that page.

Answer (score 0):

First decide on the cloud storage type. Amazon AWS  offers several different storage offerings. More detail can be [found here](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/ebs-efs-amazons3-best-cloud-storage-system).

1. S3 (Simple Storage): a static storage service meant for archiving, static web sites or media distribution.  Maximum file size of a single S3 object is 5 TB.  Performance optimized for large data transfers.
2. EBS (Electric Block Storage): persistent storage for databases, applications, storage.  16 TB storage limit.  Access only from 1 EC2 instance and contained in a single Availability Zone.
3. Amazon EFS (Elastic File System): works like a managed network file system but in the cloud. It can be shared across AWS EC2 instances.  Maximum file size is 52 TiB. Performance is more flexible than other options.

As to optimizing your data transfers, there is Amazon Storage Gateway. Or there are services such as Datapath.io.  In addition, Amazon offers AWS Direct Connect for a dedicated connection between your servers and AWS.  To provide a more consistent connection you can also purchase provisioned IOPS, at a cost.

Optimizing AWS performance is a combination of choosing the right type of storage and instances for your individual data, managing your data transfers and and efficient network pipeline.